# Unable to retrieve EWS Contacts using EmailAddress in Search Expression

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to construct a search XML expression to use with the Exchange Web Services in Java. What I try to achieve is that I can search ALL contacts by means of their email address. I already browsed their documentation but fail to get it to work. This is what I have so far:

```
String searchXmlStr ="<Restriction>"
                     + "<t:IsEqualTo>"
                     +    "<t:FieldURI FieldURI=\"contacts:EmailAddresses\"/>"
                     +    "<t:EmailAddresses>"
                     +      "<Entry Key=\""+ emailAddress +"\"/>"
                     +    "</t:EmailAddresses>"
                     + "</t:IsEqualTo>"
                     +"</Restriction>";
```

When I compile and run this piece of code, I get:

```
ERROR [jec.utils.AppLogger] status: 500
ERROR [jec.utils.AppLogger] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorSchemaValidation</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The request failed schema validation: The element 'IsEqualTo' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has invalid child element 'EmailAddresses' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'. List of possible elements expected: 'FieldURIOrConstant' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.</faultstring><detail><e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation</e:ResponseCode><e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The request failed schema validation.</e:Message><t:MessageXml xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><t:LineNumber>1</t:LineNumber><t:LinePosition>572</t:LinePosition><t:Violation>The element 'IsEqualTo' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has invalid child element 'EmailAddresses' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'. List of possible elements expected: 'FieldURIOrConstant' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.</t:Violation></t:MessageXml></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
ERROR [jec.utils.AppLogger] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorSchemaValidation</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The request failed schema validation: The element 'IsEqualTo' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has invalid child element 'EmailAddresses' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'. List of possible elements expected: 'FieldURIOrConstant' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.</faultstring><detail><e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation</e:ResponseCode><e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The request failed schema validation.</e:Message><t:MessageXml xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><t:LineNumber>1</t:LineNumber><t:LinePosition>572</t:LinePosition><t:Violation>The element 'IsEqualTo' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has invalid child element 'EmailAddresses' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'. List of possible elements expected: 'FieldURIOrConstant' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.</t:Violation></t:MessageXml></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
jec.ExchangeGeneralException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorSchemaValidation</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The request failed schema validation: The element 'IsEqualTo' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has invalid child element 'EmailAddresses' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'. List of possible elements expected: 'FieldURIOrConstant' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.</faultstring><detail><e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation</e:ResponseCode><e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The request failed schema validation.</e:Message><t:MessageXml xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><t:LineNumber>1</t:LineNumber><t:LinePosition>572</t:LinePosition><t:Violation>The element 'IsEqualTo' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has invalid child element 'EmailAddresses' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'. List of possible elements expected: 'FieldURIOrConstant' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.</t:Violation></t:MessageXml></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
    at jec.a.a.a.for(Unknown Source)
    at jec.EWSConnector.getContacts(Unknown Source)
    at betas.Main.getContactByEmail(Main.java:197)
    at betas.Main.main(Main.java:36)
jec.ExchangeGeneralException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorSchemaValidation</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The request failed schema validation: The element 'IsEqualTo' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has invalid child element 'EmailAddresses' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'. List of possible elements expected: 'FieldURIOrConstant' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.</faultstring><detail><e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation</e:ResponseCode><e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The request failed schema validation.</e:Message><t:MessageXml xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"><t:LineNumber>1</t:LineNumber><t:LinePosition>572</t:LinePosition><t:Violation>The element 'IsEqualTo' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has invalid child element 'EmailAddresses' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'. List of possible elements expected: 'FieldURIOrConstant' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.</t:Violation></t:MessageXml></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
    at jec.a.a.a.for(Unknown Source)
    at jec.EWSConnector.getContacts(Unknown Source)
    at betas.Main.getContactByEmail(Main.java:197)
    at betas.Main.main(Main.java:36)
```

**EDIT**

For the sake of completeness, I am using [this](http://javaexchangeconnector.com/) library to connect with EWS

Comment: I think this is a very simple and regularly used method to search for contacts right? Can someone just point me to my mistake??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant create a Restriction on the EmailAddresses property as this is a collection of properties so you need to use an Or restriction across the underlying 3 contact email Address properties eg

```
      <m:Restriction>
      <t:Or>
        <t:IsEqualTo>
          <t:IndexedFieldURI FieldURI="contacts:EmailAddress" FieldIndex="EmailAddress1" />
          <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
            <t:Constant Value="user@domain.com" />
          </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
        </t:IsEqualTo>
        <t:IsEqualTo>
          <t:IndexedFieldURI FieldURI="contacts:EmailAddress" FieldIndex="EmailAddress2" />
          <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
            <t:Constant Value="user@domain.com" />
          </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
        </t:IsEqualTo>
        <t:IsEqualTo>
          <t:IndexedFieldURI FieldURI="contacts:EmailAddress" FieldIndex="EmailAddress3" />
          <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
            <t:Constant Value="user@domain.com" />
          </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
        </t:IsEqualTo>
      </t:Or>
    </m:Restriction>
```

Cheers
Glen